# How to read the content of sent sms from Messages using contentObserver and contentResolver?

Tags: android, android-studio, sms, android-contentresolver

I want to read the sent message content from the mobile messages. I am not developing an sent sms reading application, but instead I want to read the recent last sent sms content form the mobile inbuilt sms app. 
I want to read the sent sms from sent items and send some notification based on the keyword in the message.

I know we have to extend ContentObserver class and use ContentResolver.

Any idea is appreciated. Thank you!

This is my Observer class SMSObserver.java,

public class SMSObserver extends ContentObserver {

```
private String lastSmsId;
private Context c;
private String phoneNumber;
int type;
String lastID;

public SMSObserver(Handler handler) {
    super(handler);
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange,Uri uri) {
    super.onChange(selfChange);
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/out");
    Cursor cur = c.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, "date DESC LIMIT 1");
    cur.moveToNext();
    //String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    if( (type == 2 || type == 1) && (!lastID.contentEquals(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id")))) ) {
        String protocol = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("protocol"));
        lastID = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        // Message sent
        if (protocol == null) {
            Log.i("SMSStatus", "SMS Sent");
        }
        // Message receive
        else {
            Log.i("SMSStatus", "SMS received");
        }

        if (smsChecker(lastID)) {
            String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
            // Optional: Check for a specific sender
            if (address.equals(phoneNumber)) {
                String message = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
                // Use message content for desired functionality
                if(message.contains("Dinner")){
                    Toast.makeText(c,"Dinner offer for 2!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Prevent duplicate results without overlooking legitimate duplicates
public boolean smsChecker(String smsId) {
    boolean flagSMS = true;

    if (smsId.equals(lastSmsId)) {
        flagSMS = false;
    }
    else {
        lastSmsId = smsId;
    }

    Log.d(lastSmsId ,"LastSmsId");
    return flagSMS;
}
```

}

I'm registering the contentObserver in a class SentSMSTrackerService.java

public class SentSMSTrackerService extends Service {

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId) {
    SMSObserver smsObserver = new SMSObserver(new Handler());
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/out"), true, smsObserver);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

I'm also giving the permission in AndroidManifest.xml

But,still i am not able to read the outgoing sms.

Comment: What is your question? You described your idea and how you're trying to tackle it, now code it. SO community won't do that for you ;)

Comment: use broadcast for that

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest of your setup, but, firstly, there is no `content://sms/out` URI. There is a `content://sms/outbox`, but that's pending messages. You probably want `content://sms/sent`. Secondly, you can't register on `content://sms/sent`. It has to be `content://sms`. Don't ask me why they did that, but that's how it is. You can still query `content://sms/sent` just fine, but this makes tracking the most recent sent message a little more involved, because your Observer is going to fire for basically any change to the `sms` table, wherever it's a sent message or otherwise.

Comment: I tried "content://sms/sent" too, even that is not working :( when i debug and see the log, i am not able to see any logs. I think the code which i have written to read sent items from messages is not working. could any of you please explain how the flow is ??

Comment: Did you change the URI in `registerContentObserver()` to `content://sms`?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, I have changed the URI in registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"). Log messages are not even printing in console.

Comment: Are you sure your `Service` is running? How are you starting it? Have you put any log prints there? Is `onChange()` being called at all? Did you put a log print first thing in that method? Which version of Android are you testing on? Do you have the `READ_SMS` permission?

Comment: Mike M.answer about listening `content://sms` works properly.